# Calculate type of value dynamically based on key property in function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have custom hook that adds to useStata function that accepts key and value props;

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export type HandleModelChangeFn<T> = (key: keyof T, value: T[typeof key]) => void;

const useModel = <T>(initialModel: T): [T, HandleModelChangeFn<T>, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState<T>(initialModel);

  const handleChange = useCallback((key: keyof T, value: T[typeof key]) => {
    setModel((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: value,
    }));
  }, []);

  return [model, handleChange, setModel];
};

export default useModel;
```

Problem is that when i use that function second parameter can be any type which exists in interface, example

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const initialModel: User = {
  name: '',
  age: 1
}

const [model, handleModelChange] = useModel(initialModel);

handleModelChange('age', 'John'); // should get error cause value is wrong type
```

key param can be 'name' or 'age', but second param has type string | number;

I want to calculate type dynamically based on key property, like when key param is 'age' ts will tell me that i passing wrong value type, cause age type is number;

Is there way to do this with typescript?

Comment: If you explicitly state the type via `useModel<User>(initialModel);` does it still transpile?

Comment: Also, what version of typescript?

Comment: typescript 4.1.2

Comment: f you explicitly state the type via useModel<User>(initialModel); does it still transpile?

yes, everything  works same way as without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to make a very small change in `HandleModelChangeFn`. You need to infer a `key`:

```js
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

// added ----------------------->  <Key extends keyof T>
export type HandleModelChangeFn<T> = <Key extends keyof T>(key: Key, value: T[Key]) => void;

const useModel = <T,>(initialModel: T): [T, HandleModelChangeFn<T>, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState<T>(initialModel);

  const handleChange = useCallback((key: keyof T, value: T[typeof key]) => {
    setModel((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: value,
    }));
  }, []);

  return [model, handleChange, setModel];
};

export default useModel;


interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const initialModel: User = {
  name: '',
  age: 1
}

const [model, handleModelChange] = useModel(initialModel);

handleModelChange('age', 'John'); // error
handleModelChange('age', 2); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEWAZzAQxgYwBYA0cAygKYzEzakCCOMwEAdkQK5qkDCmANjwEaYcAazYdK1OAF84AMygQQcAORRSQmMoDcAWABQ%20gPSG4mACZnSZuAFo79h46d2AfHDgAeANKkAnnFIADxhSJjM0OGE-CFk4ABUXfSDIWDgYXzBSOAAJTDCeUgBZCEseTjw8gHNSADEmDwS4AF5PH38gkLCIqN8Y%20JcACh6ALjg2ogA3XlZSUbiAbTaAXQBKZrcJiGAzXQM9HGY0eHYiktIeZs84gkHgJmAGXmLSuZXR%20eucvLMC5-Pyqq1eoJIioDDYfAeMgUKghOgMZgNFwuJbrRD6dwHJhHODzEBnHhEDgwP48VEtE4SEJIgZ3B7AJ4Ela7DFwLE4ir5Lic6qXE7cPiCEQDIZ%20UY9PqfKY8GZzebpTJ9HqrNEIVnuYmkkVgNQTKmkNZNNwDNV6dzmuAAOmtOtIethpAI6vN82Vo2lMydZvNUhWzNZUiI81WLO9ahgrCgTFx%20NKRE5P25gKJ5FJS12UlDyWg8EsskwrB4xw4pND%20juISg%20ZwWQAqhwoOjvUxMCBZnAjlA7pVdu5MNVRkxWCB%20KQoBn9Pp2fA6Y8eKTRvWx5dTe4W23RsplF6%20wO4ABGfRSSf7Q7wPEE%20PfX4EgFMarkuAnLWzhnzpmhhM30p36oDZT9qQ24qAAUhAeBMMozJwMYARQAoUD6F%20pw-jypD-oBwEAEzQbBEDCEAA)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you just pass an object as the parameter to the `useCallback` function.

```
...
// I use the partial interface so you can pass the keys individually
const handleChange = useCallback(obj: Partial<User>) => {
  setModel((prevState) => Object.assign(prevState, obj));
}, []);
...
```

That way typescript expects only the `name` and `age` properties from the object and what type to expect when either one is used.

```
handleModelChange({ age: 'John' }); // Error
handlModelChange({ name: 'John' }) // Success
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with one fix `(obj: Partial<User>)` but it still not solves issue with types described in question

Comment: If you use the `name` key with any value other than a `string` it will throw an error. same with the `age` key and `number`