# How to get key type in interface

Tags: typescript

Here is a problem...

titleBarContainer.tsx

```
function TitleBarContainer() {
    const systemData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.systemData)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onChangeSystemData = useCallback(
        (key: keyof SystemState, value: SystemStateType) => {
            let tempSystemData = Object.assign({}, systemData)

            tempSystemData[key] = value // It doesn't work, but not main problem.
            dispatch(changeSystemData(tempSystemData))
        },
        [dispatch, systemData]
    )
}
```

system.d.ts

```
interface SystemState {
    title: TitleStateType
    windowState: WindowStateType
    language: LanguageStateType
    mode: ModeStateType
}

type TitleStateType = string
type LanguageStateType = 'ko-KR' | 'en-US'
type WindowStateType = 'normal' | 'minimize' | 'maximize' | 'fullscreen'
type ModeStateType = 'admin' | 'user'

type SystemStateType = TitleStateType | WindowStateType | LanguageStateType | ModeStateType
```

In onChangeSystemData Function, I want to get an usual type.
For example, if 'key' is 'normal', I want 'value' type to be WindowStateType not SystemStateType.

I tried using generic type. The following is the code I tried.

titleBarContainer.tsx (previous version, doesn't work.)

```
function TitleBarContainer() {
    const systemData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.systemData)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onChangeSystemData<SystemState> = (key, value) => {
            let tempSystemData = Object.assign({}, systemData)
            tempSystemData[key] = value
            dispatch(changeSystemData(tempSystemData))
        }
}
```

system.d.ts (previous version)

```
interface SystemState {
    title: TitleStateType
    windowState: WindowStateType
    language: LanguageStateType
    mode: ModeStateType
}

type TitleStateType = string
type LanguageStateType = 'ko-KR' | 'en-US'
type WindowStateType = 'normal' | 'minimize' | 'maximize' | 'fullscreen'
type ModeStateType = 'admin' | 'user'

type SystemStateType = TitleStateType | WindowStateType | LanguageStateType | ModeStateType

interface InternalState<T> { (key: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]): void }
```

It is too diffcult to me...
Give me advises or any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu just need to infer the `key`:

```js
interface SystemState {
  title: TitleStateType
  windowState: WindowStateType
  language: LanguageStateType
  mode: ModeStateType
}

type TitleStateType = string
type LanguageStateType = 'ko-KR' | 'en-US'
type WindowStateType = 'normal' | 'minimize' | 'maximize' | 'fullscreen'
type ModeStateType = 'admin' | 'user'

type SystemStateType = TitleStateType | WindowStateType | LanguageStateType | ModeStateType

type InternalState<T> = <Key extends keyof T>(key: Key, value: T[Key]) => void


const onChangeSystemData: InternalState<SystemState> = (key, value) => {}

onChangeSystemData('windowState','minimize') // ok
onChangeSystemData('windowState','minimize222') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoE8DOkC2qxyTIDeAUMsmMGADYQBcyAKtXfoRE%20gA4TnIB3UABMA9gPaRGAdRHjJnHnwo04IAOYBXOOobIAMmq06ICrr345RwvQFlrpgpHN8AvqVJglzVo44vkAF5kbChQdU9vQw1tXTNvYIByAGtRAFoAaQAlROQAH2REiBA0gFVURMjeZFkQMQknRWqkkFEoHDgaXILEnFBgPoAvCG7CjoAPAeBh0cSYTRoaTAQoCGLKr2r7G3jmwrhhPpBZzUxoSqqUDGwIPEaA4JZaP2dvAtr63ZQC6OM4%207eyG2LyafEuyAAkuBoCBOgoADxMAB8QWQ8IyEHQyAg40gdUwyGSmNEMGYSIAFET0IwMegADTIABunU0eiYAG1aQBdACUQRRjNEwGEHlICFEIGwyAlAGEABZGUxYXAAEUIcEYUMgUFhNAR11wChRwUpmIZzJorL5gRRxHcpFlCo0SpuODVBHJiSEdXkjUSdN6-SGIz5AHpQ9Lkg6QPLFQbbu64J7vZ8-QGjlNhgAmHOJMMRnG8BCQYTYqBQNpAA)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69114482/calculate-type-of-value-dynamically-based-on-key-property-in-function/69114743#69114743)

> Why `interface InternalState<T> { <Key extends keyof T>(key: keyof T, value: T[Key]): void`  does not trigger an error?

Because `interface InternalState<T>` defines function as a method. MEthods are bivariant in typescript, this is by design. It means that if method parameters are assignable to passed arguments and vice versa - it will compile. It is unsafe to use such syntax, so try to avoid it as much as possible.

Btw, you can find some interesting examples in my [blog](https://catchts.com/) which is fully typescript dedicated

Comment: Wow, I never thought there was such a way.
Thank you for your helping. Thanks to you, I learn good information.

Comment: I have one more question.
I guess the following code is simillar with your 'type InternalState'.  
And vscode doesn't occur the problem. If you can, comfirm this plz.  
  
    "interface InternalState<T> {
        <Key extends keyof T>(key: keyof T, value: T[Key]): void
    }"

Comment: You have so many information about ts in your blog! I will have to visit to study and learn.
Thanks you, You gave me a lot of helps!